# Page Builder WYSIWYG only rendering in HTML 2.4.4 Enterprise

Tags: magento-enterprise, page-builder

We have the 2.4.4 Enterprise version of Magento (Adobe Commerce). The site was working fine, then the next day the Page Builder was not rendering at all. In the Admin this WYSIWYG editor was displaying everything in HTML. Checking on the configuration in the admin, it somehow got set to disabled, but even after enable. The Page Builder still only shows the HTML where the Page Builder was.

[image]

The error is a new one for me also where it looks like the following, where it has something to do with the vimeoWrapper. Something that was not edited at all, and it looks like require.js is not loading.

[image]

Working on it all day trying to figure this out, but have no idea how to resolve it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I don't know why it worked, but after some research I ran the command below and it started working again!

```
composer require magento/module-page-builder:2.2.2
```